# Recreating Curl Command in Python

Tags: curl, python-requests, invoice-ninja

Desperate for help here. I am trying to recreate this curl command in python that uploads a file.

```
curl -X POST https://invoicing.co/api/v1/invoices/pnelKrqVdK/upload \
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
  -H 'X-API-TOKEN: TOKEN' \
  -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' \
  -F _method=PUT \
  -F 'documents[]=@file.png'
```

The file I'm trying to upload is a pdf generated through a Saas tool that and the output is a url: https://pdf-temp-files.s3.amazonaws.com/ae7f9005db69425a874e5b2e003b9e59/time_sheet.pdf

I have the following python code written, but for the life of me I cannot get it to work

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    'X-API-TOKEN': 'token',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
}

files = {
    '_method': (None,'PUT'),
    'documents[]': 'https://pdf-temp-files.s3.amazonaws.com/ae7f9005db69425a874e5b2e003b9e59/time_sheet.pdf'
}

response = requests.post('https://invoicing.co/api/v1/invoices/pnelKrqVdKz/upload', headers=headers, files=files)

response.status_code
```

Error I'm getting is 405 {'message': 'Method not supported for this route'}

Any ideas?

Comment: requests.put( ... ) for a put?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use the `requets.put()` method. And I think the JSON payload in the variable `files` is formatted improperly for its contents. Hopefully the answer below moves you closer to a working program.

```
        import requests
        
        headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            'X-API-TOKEN': 'token',
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        }

# Uploaded document name
        remote_name = 'https://pdf-temp-files.s3.amazonaws.com/ae7f9005db69425a874e5b2e003b9e59/time_sheet.pdf'    
# Name/path of the document on your local machine
        local_name = "my_time_sheet.pdf"
# Now the put data, `open` the local file.
        files = [ ("file", (remote_name, open(local_name, "rb"), "application/pdf")), ]
     
        response = requests.put('https://invoicing.co/api/v1/invoices/pnelKrqVdKz/upload', headers=headers, files=files)
        
        response.status_code
```

Comment: Thank you for helping. I did get the following error when putting the pdf url in []


  File "/Users/zackmccarty/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 151, in _encode_files
    fn, fp, ft, fh = v

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 1)

Comment: I can't really help more than that. If you post a comment with a link to the AWS documentation I might get a chance to read it and help a bit more?

Comment: I added some code. Might help